# Jenkins [ERROR] - XTrigger exception - windows

Tags: ant, jenkins, ivy, jenkins-plugins

I get the below trigger exception for Ivy trigger, So i checked the xml it is complaining about (in the temp folder). I found the xml is not valid, its because of some path strings with double quotes ("") inside double quotes ("") . but the same configuration is producing valid xml in linux and everything works properly as it should be. I am very confused, can anyone help me understand this... cheers...

> [IvyTrigger] - Poll with an Ivy script
>
> Polling started on 10-Apr-2013 11:28:31 Polling for the job
>   ProjectName Looking nodes where the poll can be run. Looking for the
>   last built on node.
>
> Polling on master. Given job Ivy file value:
>   ProjectName/conf/ProjectName/ivy.xml Given job Ivy settings file
>   value: ProjectName/conf/ProjectName/ivysettings.xml Resolved job Ivy
>   file value:
>   C:\Users\r.ramachandran.jenkins\jobs\ProjectName\workspace\ProjectName\conf\ProjectName\ivy.xml
>   Resolved job Ivy settings file value:
>   C:\Users\r.ramachandran.jenkins\jobs\ProjectName\workspace\ProjectName\conf\ProjectName\ivysettings.xml
>   Given job  properties file path:
>   ProjectName/conf/ProjectName/versions.properties Resolved properties
>   file value :
>   C:\Users\r.ramachandran.jenkins\jobs\ProjectName\workspace\ProjectName\conf\ProjectName\versions.properties
>   Temporary properties file path is props7098303975969813724props
>   [ERROR] - XTrigger exception: java.text.ParseException: failed to load
>   settings from
>   file:/C:/apps/apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/temp/file5208145617326820606.tmp:
>   Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>". Recording context. Check changes in next
>   poll.
>
> Polling complete. Took 35 ms. No changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing the same issue on a node where /tmp is less than 1GB so I guess its because files are getting deleted/corrupted.

Try cleaning /tmp or increasing its size.